# code for reversing an integer in cpp using operators

Tags: c++, operators, reverse

the code is for reversing the input decimal whether negative or positive .if the value of decimal exceeds as max size of int in 32 bit system then return 0.why my code is not working...help me finding the bug .i have attached the code.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
float reverseint(int x)
{
    int digit[10];
    int i = 0;
    float revnum = 0;
//store digits of number x
    while (x != 0)
    {
        digit[i] = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        i++;
    }
    i--;
//reversing number x
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        int j = 0;
        revnum = (digit[i] * pow(10, j)) + revnum;
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    return revnum;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n < 0)
    {
        if (n < -pow(2, 31))
            cout << 0 << endl;
        cout << -reverseint(-n);
    }
    if (n > 0)
    {
        if (n > (pow(2, 31) - 1))
            cout << 0 << endl;
        cout << (reverseint(n)) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A few notes: Don't `pow` `int`s. They have an annoying tendency to wind up off by one courtesy of the crazy stuff `pow` has to do with floating point numbers to compute the result. The classic example used to be `pow(5,2)` returning 24.99999999999999 and truncating to 24. Compilers these days are smart enough to avoid the problem some of the time, but you're probably better off being explicit and using bit shifting. 2 to the Xth power is `1 <<X` and the modern computer can spit that out in one operation, assuming the compiler doesn't do the work ahead of the time and store a constant.

Comment: If possible, don't waste your time with numbers. Read the number in as a string and then reverse the string. Not only does the Standard library have tools to do the job for you, if you have to do it the hard way, the digits are already split up into separate characters for you. Easy pickin's.

Comment: Don't write such cramped code. The density makes it harder to spot mistakes and exploitable patterns. Extra white space won't slow the program down, but it will slow YOU down. You're the one getting paid, not the computer. Get the job done quickly and hit the pub, spend time with the family, do more work for more money, whatever you want. Just do something more useful than trying to reason with hard-to-read code.

Comment: Here's what I'm talking about with compilers being smart: https://godbolt.org/z/7PvocMMa8 Look at that cheeky bugger. Where's the call to `pow`? It's right here, suckah: `mov     esi, -2147483648`. Compiler did the math, made a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `j` variable on every while loop on `reverseint` function.

```
float reverseint(int x)
{
    int digit[10];
    int i = 0;
    float revnum = 0;
//store digits of number x
    while (x != 0)
    {
        digit[i] = x % 10;
        x = x / 10;
        i++;
    }
    i--;
//reversing number x
    int j = 0; /// Correct place.
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        //int j = 0; /// Wrong. j will be always 0 on every loop. revnum  will be sum of digits on variable x.
        revnum = (digit[i] * pow(10, j)) + revnum;
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    return revnum;
}
```